# How to show different pages from the center element of JFrame (having set to BorderLayout)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GuiController extends JFrame {

    private CentreFrameController centreFrameController;
    private CustomerPage customerPage;
    private LoginPage loginPage;
    public GuiController(){
        centreFrameController=new CentreFrameController(this);      
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());      

        add(centreFrameController,BorderLayout.CENTER);     

        setTitle("Courier System-Login Page");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(550,650);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }   
}
```

### `CentreFrameController`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CentreFrameController extends JPanel {

    private GuiController guiController;
    private CustomerPage customerPage;
    private LoginPage loginPage;
    public CentreFrameController(GuiController guiController){
        this.guiController=guiController;
        loginPage=new LoginPage(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(loginPage,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        loginPage.addLoginPageListener(new LoginPageListener(){
            public void getLoginPageReply(int reply) {
                switch(reply){
                case 0:System.out.println("Customer login sucess");
                setCustomerHomePage();
                break;
                case 1:System.out.println("Admin login success");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void setCustomerHomePage(){
        customerPage=new CustomerPage(this,loginPage);
        add(customerPage,BorderLayout.CENTER);///This is the part which is not working
    }
}
```

The aim of this part of the code is:

1. I want to make the `GuiController` frame have some common style for my application on all pages (irrespective of any activity)
2. The `GuiController` frame gives the center element styling of the `BorderLayout` to the `CentreFrameController` panel
3. Now the `CentreFrameController` should switch pages after hearing from the `LoginListener`. But here,when it hears from `LoginListener`, it's not adding the `CustomerPage` to its layout (please note that here, the `CustomerPage` class is made to extend `JPanel` and I have not uploaded that because its not really necessary).

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating how you could use `CardLayout` as suggested by  Andrew Thompson:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiController extends JFrame {

    private boolean isRedShowing;

    public GuiController(){

        setTitle("CardLayout Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        CentreFrameController centreFrameController = new CentreFrameController();
        centreFrameController.showRedPane();
        isRedShowing = true;
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(centreFrameController,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton toggle = new JButton("Toggle");
        toggle.addActionListener(e ->{
            if(! isRedShowing) {
                centreFrameController.showRedPane();
            } else {
                centreFrameController.showYelloPane();
            }
            isRedShowing = ! isRedShowing;
        });
        add(toggle,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GuiController();
    }
}

class CentreFrameController extends JPanel {

    public final String YELLOW_PAGE = "yellow page";
    public final String RED_PAGE = "red page";
    private final CardLayout cLayout;

    public CentreFrameController(){

        cLayout = new CardLayout();
        setLayout(cLayout);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
        add(YELLOW_PAGE, new YellowPane());
        add(RED_PAGE, new RedPane());
    }

    //two convenience methods that encapsulate CardLayout#show(Container, String)
    void showRedPane() {
        cLayout.show(this, RED_PAGE);
    }

    void showYelloPane() {
        cLayout.show(this, YELLOW_PAGE);
    }
}

class RedPane extends JPanel{

    RedPane(){
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
}

class YellowPane extends JPanel{

    YellowPane(){
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
```

You control which card shows by using `CarrdLayout` [show](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String)).

---

[image]