# Java- how to use a CardLayout in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

i want to implement a JFrame to switch between two or more windows with different contents. I think a CardLayout is the best option here.

But I don't know how to use that.
I have different "windows" with different functionalities. For example I click on a button at the main menu and this leads me to the next "page" (next window).

[image: picture]

Thx all in advance

Comment: Which UI designer plugin do you use? It could be helpful to know it!

Comment: @0x1C1B thanks for your answer. I downloaded the windows builder

Comment: If you want to do it by writing code (rather than by UI designer) see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013230/3992939)

Comment: @c0der thx for your answer I wanted to do it by the UI designer but I don't know how :/

Comment: If learning swing is a goal, I would recommend coding.