# Why the show method of card layout doesn't work in this case?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jcombobox, cardlayout

I am trying to switch between different  panels using `JComboBox` and `CardLayout` but any switching doesn't occur. Printing the `ItemSelected` was revealed that `ItemListener` is working correctly and also the accuracy of card layout was confirmed by examining other methods like `next()`, `previous()`, ...

I would really appreciate if anybody can help me out with this issue.

```
public class MyPanel exends JPanel {

public MyPanel() {
    setBodyPanel();
}
private void setBodyPanel() {
    card = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(noBodyPanel);
    cards.add(formPanel);
    cards.add(jsonPanel);
    cards.add(binaryFilePanel);

    String comboBoxItems[] = {"No Body", "Form Data", "JSON", "Binary Data"};
    JComboBox cbBodyType = new JComboBox(comboBoxItems);
    cbBodyType.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                cl.show(cards,e.getItem().toString());
                System.out.println(e.getItem().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    JPanel cbPanel = new JPanel();
    cbPanel.add(cbBodyType);
    add(cbPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(cards,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}}
```

I deleted the unnecessary codes

Comment: You need to add the `JPanel` with the same name you use to retrieve it:  `add("No Body", noBodyPanel);`. See a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013230/3992939)

Comment: *"I deleted the unnecessary codes"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `JPanel` with the same name you use to retrieve it.
Here is an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)<sup>1</sup> demonstrating it :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
        setBodyPanel();
    }
    private void setBodyPanel() {

        String comboBoxItems[] = {"No Body", "Form Data", "JSON", "Binary Data"};
        JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        for(String name : comboBoxItems){
            cards.add(name, getPanel(name));
        }

        JComboBox<String> cbBodyType = new JComboBox<>(comboBoxItems);
        cbBodyType.addItemListener(e -> {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                cl.show(cards,(String)e.getItem());
            }
        });

        add(cards,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel cbPanel = new JPanel();
        cbPanel.add(cbBodyType);
        add(cbPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private Component getPanel(String name) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JLabel(name +" panel"));
        return p;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It is highly recommended to post mre or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) when asking and answering