# How to instance a JPanel into panel in Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, windowbuilder

Sorry if I might mix terms up. So I have a basic application where I would press the button and Jpanel1 with a label in it, would then switch/replace to JPanel2 that'll have a picture in it, all within the panel.
[image]

The JPanel inside the box would change from Jpanel1 to JPanel 2 after pressing the button. So is their a way to instance a JPanel in a panel or JFrame? I can't find the method on how to fill the panel with the JPanel.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: See [CardLayout Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013230/3992939)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using `layeredPane` with a `card layout`. Then I placed a panel using the center `Border Layout`, then instanced the `JPanel` as the panel from a different class.

[Picture of Windowbuilder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvVXb.png)

```
    panelPPBrowser = new JPanel();
    layeredPane.add(panelPPBrowser, "name_216881785358769");
    panelPPBrowser.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    
    panelBrowser panelBrowserCon = new panelBrowser();
    panelPPBrowser.add(panelBrowserCon, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, /*layout.location*/);
```

You mean add

Answer (score 1):

The exact way to do this depends on the LayoutManager you use. I suggest checking out the [Visual Guide to LayoutManagers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). For example, if you use a `BorderLayout`, you can add a panel to the center and then replace it with a different panel when the user clicks a button.